How to check if object is grabbed with left or right hand in Unity VR?
I'm using the Unity XRGrabInteractable to grab objects in VR. But I want some behavior to be different if the object is grabbed in left vs. right hand.
I tried inheriting the XRGrabInteractable and checking at the OnSelectEntering method whether the interactor is right hand or left hand, but I couldn't figure out how to check that from the SelectEnterEventArgs.
I looked at the Unity API docs but couldn't find the method or property to indicate which hand it is.
How would this be done?
Here is the code I'm trying to write:
public class ItemGrab : XRGrabInteractable
{
    protected override void OnSelectEntering(SelectEnterEventArgs interactor)
    {
        base.OnSelectEntering(interactor);

        if( /* CHECK IF RIGHT HAND */) 
            //do right hand thing
        else
            //do left hand thing
    }
}


Add an interactable layer to controllers (see attach)
The method inside grabbed object script:
 public void GrabWeapon(SelectEnterEventArgs grabData)
        {
            var rightHand = (grabData.interactorObject.interactionLayers & (1 << 1)) == 0;
            var handString = rightHand ? "Right" : "Left";
            Debug.Log($"GrabWeapon {handString} hand");
        }

Object with listener script and XRGrabInteractable
XR Controllers setup
